# Can't Find variable '$' but I've included jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Nothing happens when I press the button with the id test. I do get an error message in the debug of my console though that states:

> ReferenceError: Can't Find variable '$'.

I believe this is a jQuery error, but I already have it imported. Here's the code:

```
  <html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../../assets/ico/favicon.ico">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.parsecdn.com/js/parse-1.2.18.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $("#test").click(function() {
        alert("Handler for .click() called.");
    });
  </script>

    <title>Panic App</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="./css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="./css/cover.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Just for debugging purposes. Don't actually copy this line! -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="../../assets/js/ie8-responsive-file-warning.js"></script><![endif]-->

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>

  <body>
  <div id="loginModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
  <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
          <h1 class="text-center">Login</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
          <form class="form col-md-12 center-block">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" value="b" class="form-control input-lg" id="username" placeholder="Email">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="password" value="a" class="form-control input-lg" id="password"placeholder="Password">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <button class="bn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" id="test" value="Sign In">Sign In</button>
              <span class="pull-right"><a href="#">Register</a></span><span><a href="#">Need help?</a></span>
            </div>
          </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
          <div class="col-md-12">
          <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Cancel</button>
      </div>  
      </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>

    <div class="site-wrapper">

      <div class="site-wrapper-inner">

        <div class="cover-container">

          <div class="masthead clearfix">
            <div class="inner">
              <h3 class="masthead-brand">Panic</h3>
              <ul class="nav masthead-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Features</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="inner cover">
            <h1 class="cover-heading">Stay Safe.</h1>
            <p class="lead">Panic is a beautiful emergency notification system like no other. Using the power of cloud computing, Panic innovates in ways you've never seen.</p>
            <p class="lead">
              <button class="btn btn-lg btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#loginModal">Sign Up.</button>  
            </p>
          </div>

          <div class="mastfoot">
            <div class="inner">
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>

      </div>

    </div>

    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./js/docs.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: We don't have particularly sensitive ears here, but nevertheless the title could do with rewording.

Comment: You load jQuery at the very end, but try to use it before. This doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move your code after the jQuery initialization:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="./js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="./js/docs.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $("#test").click(function() {
        alert("Handler for .click() called.");
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 7):

You try to call `$` on line 11 of that source code (and maybe also in the script on line 9).

You don't include jQuery until the very end.

You have to include jQuery *before* you try to use it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the jQuery library above your script. Also your script will work only if you keep it inside the `$(document).ready()` function.